# SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter - BaseAddress

Tags: java, web-service, spring, jax-ws

Criei um Web Service com JAX-WS e usei o Spring para colocar on-line e também para diminuir o uso de XML.
Problema é que quando declaro o SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter no arquivo de configuração do Spring tenho que colocar o atributo baseAddress que é o host, o default é localhost:8080 e quando está assim não consigo acessar o WebService através de outra máquina.
Ex: Vou em outra máquina e digito o IP da minha e não acesso o Web Service na referida na porta, agora se eu configuro o baseAddress com meu-ip:8080 eu acesso de qualquer máquina e não acesso por localhost:8080/

Se fosse um projeto de estudo não tinha problema mas tenho que colocar em homologação e produção e toda vez antes de gerar o .war tenho alterar e colocar o ip.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="br" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">$url</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">$user</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">$pass</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">86400</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="messageDispatcherServlet" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet">
</bean>

<!-- Localhost -->
<bean class= "org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
    <property name="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:7078/" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sugiro utilizar essa configuração:

dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

configuração de serviço

```
<wss:binding url="/service/enderecoSeuServico">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#seuBeanAnotadoCom @WebService" /> 
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

onde os prefixos são:

```
xmlns:ws= "http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
```

dessa forma não importa o baseAddress do seu servidor

Comment: Já tenho ela no pom.xml =/

Comment: então basta substituir seu bean SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter pelos bindings, alterei a resposta com a definição dos prefixos

Comment: E toda vez que eu adicionar um Web Service novo vou ter que adicionar no XML também, estou fugindo disso rsrs. Vou deixar da forma como está, só altero o endereço na hora de gerar o .war